# Testing service account requests using the Google OAuth playground?

Tags: google-oauth

Is there way to use the developers.google.com/oauthplayground to test a service account request?

How do you specify the service account user's email, client-id and public key?

Answer (score 4):

You can't test service account request in OAuth playground.  It is best if you write a simple script and test it that way instead.  Check out the Drive Service account docs.  It has code samples and detailed instruction on setting one up.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

Comment: Thanks, It turns out Google enterprise support will not investigate a problem if it can't be reproduced in the playground. In that situation, I have to configure the service user so it can reproduce the problem without using the service account. That is a little more work so I wanted to confirm that I can't test with the service account directly.